# How do you play music at startup?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio

How do you play music only on startup? I want to play music only on startup. Right  now I have it in the viewDidLoad method. Every time I come back to that page the sound plays. Can I make it only play once?

I found out. You put it in an applicationDidBecomeActive statement:

Code:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[player setVolume:1];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/PBLTune.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
player.numberOfLoops = 0;

if (player == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [player setVolume:0.1];

[player play];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code the plays that music to `-applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Without seeing the code, I can't suggest how to make it play only once.

Comment: To make it play once, try setting `numberOfLoops` to 1

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: is this in the app delegate file? Yes it is.